# How to Get And List All files from a Github Repository

Tags: git, github3.py

I am trying to list all files from a Github repository.

```
def listFiles(self, filepath):
    git = githubHandler(GH_USERNAME, GH_PASSWORD)
    gh, repo, branch = git.connect_to_github()        
    tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()
    print repo.blob
    print branch
```

So far I can only output the repo branch and name.
Any ideas?

Comment: In what format? You could try `git ls-tree -r <commit-ish>` in the cmd line. There must be a corresponding function in github3.py.

Comment: I am looking..so far I can only list the repo branches and master. It would be so cool if we can actually create a function for this for github3 which i Love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it after struggling for a while:

```
def list_filenames(self, filepath):
    git = githubHandler(GH_USERNAME, GH_PASSWORD)
    gh, repo, branch = git.connect_to_github()        
    tree = branch.commit.commit.tree.recurse()
    for filename in tree.tree: 
        print("[*] Found file {0}".format(filename.path)) 
        print filename.path
    return None
```